# Current source output

Tags: current, source

What can I do to eliminate the output voltage when there is no load on my circuit, even if there is any level on V2?
I have do develop a current source that doesn't provide output when no load. Thanks[image]

Comment: Try adding a pullup (to V1) to the gates of Q3/Q4 so the PNPs are not enabled when V2 is low.

Comment: How will you know there is no load without attempting to pass current? An ideal current source has infinite output voltage when open.

Comment: CrossRoads, this pullup doesn't solve the problem.
Thats the point Spehro, I need to make some alteration to contour it.

Comment: Q5 limits the voltage on R2, add a similar Q6 on the other branch.
Add a current sensor in the path (could be a resistor), if the current is higher than a selected value, drive the base of Q6 high, otherwise set the base of Q6 to a low voltage, but not to low in order to be able to get output current.